# How call twitter API Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have created a App in twitter account . I trying to fetch tweet for particular hashtag but  I don't know how to run URL and Use access token in this. And I am unable to find JS SDK. I am new for twitter and confused about this.

I have find out this code but it is getting 400 bad request error. Please help me

```js
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?",
        type: "GET",
        data: {count:10 },//cursor: "-1", 
               // screen_name: "sitestreams" },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data) { alert('hello!'); console.log(data);},
        error: function(html) { alert(html); },
        beforeSend: setHeader
    });
    function setHeader(xhr) {
        if(xhr && xhr.overrideMimeType) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="qqqq7a3ansbRqqqTfOBdX4hn2sQJp72a", oauth_nonce="a3df1878qqqqe0b6d644f6ac0fd3a354725a", oauth_signature="%qqqqq2BhZ4eYIjnJc0fcHU2VHhrjvR0Ns%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1435qqqqq579396", oauth_token="468141855-Id6phQoOE66n9CBzAdqqqqwEUAuQI2qqqqTBmxGyUHL9xarx", oauth_version="1.0"');
    }
```

How to use these outh signatures

OAuth Signing Results

> Important: This will only be valid for a few minutes. Also remember
>   the cURL command will actually execute the request.  null 
>   nullSignature base string  null 
>   nullGET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Ffriends%2Flist.json&amp%253Binclude_user_entities%3Dfalse%26amp%253Bscreen_name%3Dtwitterapi%26amp%253Bskip_status%3Dtrue%26cursor%3D-1%26oauth_consumer_key%3D7a3addsssdnsbRTfOBdX4hn2sQJp72a%26oauth_nonce%3D84d92acbc6ssssddd8ff3ecd2fa72e8dc64c4fc%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1445456635455642473%26oauth_token%3D468141855-Id6phQoOE66n9CBzAdwsddEUAuQI2TBmxGyUHL9xarx%26oauth_version%3D1.0
>   null  nullAuthorization header  null  nullAuthorization: OAuth
>   oauth_consumer_key="7a3ansbRsssssTfOBdX4hn2sQJp72a",
>   oauth_nonce="84d92acbsssc68ff3ecd2fa72e8dc64c4fc",
>   oauth_signature="DThJZIUNssDNA8rtHt7R6x04aAGVM%3D",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1435642473",
>   oauth_token="468145641855-Id6phQoOE66ssn9CBzAdwEUAssuQI2TBmxGyUHL9xarx",
>   oauth_version="1.0"  null  nullcURL command  null  nullcurl --get
>   'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json' --data
>   'amp%3Binclude_user_entities=false&amp%3Bscreen_name=twitterapi&amp%3Bskip_status=true&cursor=-1'
>   --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="7a3ansbRTsssfOBdX4hn2sQJp72a",
>   oauth_nonce="84d9ss2acbc68ff3ecd2fa72e8dc64c4fc",
>   oauth_signature="DThJZIUNDssssNA8rtHt7R6x04aAGVM%3D",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="143564542473",
>   oauth_token="468141851235-Id6phQoOE66n9CBsssszAdwEUAuQI2TBmxGyUHL9xarx",
>   oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose  null  null

Comment: You need to have an ssl connection to use them. Otherwise you'll get a bad request error like you have been

Comment: @leb i am working on local server. thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not approaching this correctly I'm not surprised you're getting a 400 error. What you're doing is that you're request an OAuth sign which is only valid once manually executed (through the twitter developer app).

I would suggest you use [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) for JS and use `T.get` to look up hashtags. Your results will still show up in `json` and you'll be able to extract them from there.

Comment: Is there node.js required or not.

Comment: Yes it does require it

Comment: Any way to get twitter feed and other API call without server side call.

Comment: Unfortunately no unless you want to use the basic [search](https://twitter.com/search-home) feature. I'm assuming you're wanting that because of the rate limit?

Comment: Thanks @leb for support . please vote my question if you think it is right

Comment: @SawanDhanotiya I did, glad I could help.